# Django DRF - Send email with html template - django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, email, django-rest-framework

I've added sending emails in my Django project and now I want to use html templates for the content of these emails. I've created a templates folder and put my template in there. Then I added the template path to TEMPLATES in settings.py. (See code below)

But now I'm getting the following error.

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: activate_email.html
```

Even though the template exists:

[image]

views.py

```
# import file with html content
html_version = 'activate_email.html' # 'templates/activate_email.html' also doesn't work
html_message = render_to_string(html_version, {'context': context, })

email = EmailMessage(
    'MySubject',  
    html_message,
    'info@example.co',  
    [user.email],  
)
email.send()
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'django_backend/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction what I'm doing wrong?

I'm using Django 4.0 and DRF 3.13.1

Comment: try this ```'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],```

Comment: Not sure where `BASE_DIR` points to in relation to `django_backend` directory. Have you tried `[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]`?

Comment: Ah silly mistake, django_backend is the project name. Now it works! Thanks